# How do I create a permanent alias file in PowerShell core?

Tags: powershell-core

I'm attempting to transition from PowerShell 5.1 to PowerShell Core 7.0 on Windows. In PowerShell, I have a permanent alias file at `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1`. However, when I launch the core terminal, these aliases aren't loaded. Any idea what I can do so that this file is also executed when starting core?

Comment: Put them in `$profile.AllUsersAllHosts` - for a default PowerShell 7 on Windows that's `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\profile.ps1`

Comment: Perfect, this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding Mathias R. Jessen's comment so that this question has an answer.

"Put them in `$profile.AllUsersAllHosts` for a default PowerShell 7 on Windows that's `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\profile.ps1`" – Mathias R. Jessen

Answer (score 2):

Write a function in `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` and it'll be set as alias.

For example in `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`:

```
function open-profile{
    notepad $PSHOME\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
}
```

Now you can run it as a command in powershell core as `open-profile`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers did not work for me with Windows 10 / PowerShell 7.3.4

`. $profile` complaint that this file was missing:

`%userprofile%\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

I created the file and for testing added

```
Set-Alias k kubectl
Set-Alias tf terraform
```

After another `. $profile` the shortcuts worked.

Answer (score 0):

*TvdH's method worked for me*.

I had to first create the PowerShell directory under `%userprofile%/Documents` and then add the aliases into `%userprofile%\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` file.

Restart the windows terminal and try out the new aliases at the prompt.